# Sort matrix according to first column in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix with two columns of the following form:

```
1 349
1 393
1 392
4 459
3 49
3 32
2 94
```

I would like to sort this matrix in increasing order based on the first column but I would like to keep the corresponding values in the second column.

The output would look like this:

```
1 349
1 393
1 392
2 94
3 49
3 32
4 459
```

Comment: Best answers so far that I've found:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r?rq=1

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Read the data:

```
foo <- read.table(text="1 349
  1 393
  1 392
  4 459
  3 49
  3 32
  2 94")
```

And sort:

```
foo[order(foo$V1),]
```

This relies on the fact that `order` keeps ties in their original order. See `?order`.

Comment: Good idea, +1. Or `foo[order(foo$V1,foo$V2),]` for people who struggle with `with` (like me).

Comment: What about when I want to sort it in decreasing order? // I have tried it but doesn't works:
`foo[order(foo$V1), decreasing = TRUE]`

Comment: The `decreasing` parameter needs to go into the `order` function, not the `[` operator: `foo[order(foo$V1,decreasing=TRUE),]`

Comment: `foo[order(foo$V1),]` works if `foo` is `data.frame`. If `foo` is `matrix` use `foo[order(foo[, "V1"]),]`

Comment: The answer works with a data.frame not with a matrix as @Wakan Tanka pointed out

Answer (score 12):

Creating a `data.table` with `key=V1` automatically does this for you. Using Stephan's data `foo`

```
> require(data.table)
> foo.dt <- data.table(foo, key="V1")
> foo.dt
   V1  V2
1:  1 349
2:  1 393
3:  1 392
4:  2  94
5:  3  49
6:  3  32
7:  4 459
```

Comment: Nice, +1! Is it documented that `data.table` keeps ties in the key in the original order? If not, could this potentially change in later versions of `data.table`? Changes like these can be extremely hard to find if they break scripts written with an older package version.

Comment: +1 too. @StephanKolassa, agreed. Yes this is documented and guaranteed. From `?data.table`: `The order of the rows within each group is preserved, as is the order of the groups.`.  And in `?setkey` (in its own paragraph): `The sort is stable; i.e., the order of ties (if any) is preserved.`.

Comment: @Arun, OP had asked about sorting a `matrix`; is converting into a `data.table` and sorting better (=faster) than any other method that uses matrices directly? I was under the impression that dealing with matrices is faster than the list like `data.xxx` objects when possible.

Answer (score 10):

Be aware that if you want to have values in the reverse order, you can easily do so:

```
> example = matrix(c(1,1,1,4,3,3,2,349,393,392,459,49,32,94), ncol = 2)
> example[order(example[,1], decreasing = TRUE),]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4  459
[2,]    3   49
[3,]    3   32
[4,]    2   94
[5,]    1  349
[6,]    1  393
[7,]    1  392
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in a matrix named `foo`, the line you would run is

`foo.sorted=foo[order(foo[,1]), ]`

The `order(foo[,1])` expression returns the elements from the first column of `foo` in ascending order.
The `foo[x, ]` expression returns the rows of `foo` ordered according to the vector of indices `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `data.table`.

This is what you need `A[order(A[,1]), ]`, where `A` is the matrix of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works like a charm unless you're applying it to a vector. Since a vector is non-recursive, you'll get an error like this

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

You can use `[` in that case

```
foo[order(foo["V1"]),]
```

Comment: `foo[order(foo[, "V1"]),]` for matrices