# Sort matrix rows by row means

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `m` :

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 9, 0, 0), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
m

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    8    3
[2,]    1    2    4
[3,]    9    0    0
```

I calculate the `rowMeans(m)` :

```
r.mean <- rowMeans(m)
r.mean

[1] 4.000000 2.333333 3.000000
```

How can I use  `r.mean` to sort my matrix `m` from the maximum mean to the minimum :

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    8    3
[2,]    9    0    0
[3,]    1    2    4
```

Comment: Take a squiz at `?order`.

Comment: (here's an example:http://stackoverflow.com/q/14359726/489704)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

```
m[ order(rowMeans(m)), ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    4
[2,]    9    0    0
[3,]    1    8    3
```

From the maximum mean to the minimum, by adding `, decreasing = T`

```
m[ order(rowMeans(m), decreasing = T), ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    8    3
[2,]    9    0    0
[3,]    1    2    4
```