# How can i create a matrix that has all the rows reordered such that one column is in decreasing order?

Tags: r

My current matrix has 3 columns, the first columns is letters, second is numbers and the third is the first and second columns concatenated together. I am trying to sort the second column in decreasing order and have the other two columns change according to the middle column. This is the code i have but the result is not in decreasing order.

```
matrix1[order(matrix1[column2], decreasing = TRUE),]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPgrf.png)

Comment: To subset a matrix, you use `matrix[rows, columns]`. So `matrix1[column2]` is putting `column2` in the "rows" spot. Try `matrix1[order(matrix1[, column2], decreasing = TRUE),]`... and I'm assuming `column2` is a variable containing a string with the name of your 2nd column here. If you want to refer to the second column by number, try `matrix1[order(matrix1[, 2], decreasing = TRUE),]`. If none of this is working, please share reproducible data, like `dput(head(matrix1))` , which will by copy/pasteable and include all the relevant structure of your data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359726/sort-matrix-according-to-first-column-in-r

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `matrix1[column2]`. You're missing a comma, so you're flattening your 2D matrix to a 1D matrix and the indices are getting messed up. Try `matrix1[,"column2"]` or `matrix1$column2`.

Comment: If it's actually a matrix `$` won't work... (though I'll admit that's a pretty big 'if' at this point)

Comment: I tried the "column2" part but the values did not go in decreasing order (i attached an image by the question)

Comment: Ah, its because the values in your second column aren't stored as numbers. Notice how they have quotes, and they're in decreasing order by their first digit? You could do the brute force option and use `order(as.numeric(paste(matrix[,"column2"])), decreasing = TRUE)`. If you're planning on actually using them as numbers later on, though, I'd convert it to a data.frame now and save yourself some trouble.